# Is reading systematically collected articles one-by-one enough for publication or I should have any further stategy?

Tags: publications, literature-review, review-databases

I've searched the articles, abstracts, and keywords using Scopus.
I narrowed down the time for the exciting period/range.
I limited the subject area to the relevant ones.

Now I've 40 papers instead of 3000. I don't know what the next step is. I want to do a systematic review and publish my findings. I've collected the research questions. Still, I don't find any good description of how to process them. Should I read all of them? Or is it enough to walk through the abstracts?

I want my paper accepted, so one solution is not the best, I need an elegant solution. :-)

Comment: "I don't know what the next step is." Much like the Cheshire Cat, I must ask you where you want to go... Otherwise I can't tell you the next step to take. Can you please clarify your context? For example, are you a Master Degree student, or a (Under)Graduate student, or just a teenager? Why did you start a Systematic Literature Review? There is noone providing you guidance to you on your organisation? Or you are not enrolled in anything?

Answer (score 5):

People who write review articles are experts in their respective fields for a large number of years.

The answer to your question is that this approach is not going to benefit you, especially if the only goal is to publish a paper.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, which is reminiscent of my downvoted answer here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/152333/109931. ;-)

Comment: "People who write review articles are experts in their respective fields for a large number of years." Not necessarily. I'm doing a Systematic Literature Review as an assignment to a Master Degree course's discipline. Noone in Academia know me so far, noone has told I'm an expert in my field for decades.

Comment: This is a flawed argument. Review papers support PhD students to narrow down their research questions. For example, if someone is doing a PhD, they have already spent many years in the field and now are narrowing down to one specific area of expertise.  And their review of the field could be as good as any expert. The reason this answer is getting upvoted is because the person who asked this question seems more interested in getting published than the research questions. Most of the academicians are like that including the so called 'experts'.

Answer (score 2):

Well, maybe not. Reading a bunch of articles and then extracting some things from them isn't quite enough. You also need to *understand* the articles you read so that your paper is more than what a bot could do.

In fact, what you need to write a good paper is to achieve *insight*, if not enlightenment, from those papers into the topic(s) they discuss.

I'm currently reading a book that is important to my current project. It is very dense and full of "information", but it is terribly difficult to draw insight from it without spending a lot of time on each page and, in this case, drawing a lot of figures.

If you can express that insight in an understandable way, then you have made a contribution.